# ffmpeg: How to place multiple overlays and fade out the topmost properly

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, overlay

I'm trying to place several overlays on top of each other and fade out the topmost after some frames. Therefore I'm using 2 .png files which should be placed on the final video in the following order:

> fademe.png <-- Topmost overlay, should be faded after some frames
>
> overlay.png <-- second overlay, always visible
>
> movie.mov <-- a movie as the bottom layer

I'm using this code to create a PNG encoded .mov from the overlays:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i fademe.png -loop 1 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:0]fade=out:25:25[fad];[1:0][fad] overlay" -vframes 55 -vcodec png overlay.mov
```

Then I'm using ffmbc to place overlay.mov on top of another video.

(I'm using ffmbc because the final output is going to be ProRes4444)

```
ffmbc -y -threads 0 -i movie.mov -vf "movie=overlay.mov [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay [out]"  -vcodec libx264 faded.mp4
```

The output video looks nice until fading starts and `fademe.png [fad]` seems to get faded to white and doing some strange things to the colours below until it disappears.

When I'm changing the order in the last `overlay` from `[1:0][fad] overlay` to `[fad][1:0] overlay` so it looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i fademe.png -loop 1 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:0]fade=out:25:25[fad];[fad][1:0] overlay" -vframes 55 -vcodec png overlay.mov
```

the fading looks right, but `overlay.png [1:0]` shouldn't be the topmost layer.

My guess is that something wrong happens to the alpha-channel on my first try.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution:

First I created a intermediate movie of the fading logo

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1  -i fademe.png -filter_complex "fade=out:25:25" -vframes 55 -vcodec png fademe.mov
```

then I used this command with ffmbc

```
ffmbc -i movie.mov -vf "movie=overlay.png [over]; movie=fademe.mov [fade]; [in][over] overlay [inter]; [inter][fade] overlay [out]" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

...Heureka!!!

The logo sitting on top of the composition is fading away nice and smooth!

Answer (score 7):

It should not be necessary to use two commands and create an intermediate file with an alpha channel.  A single command with 3 inputs, 2 overlay filters, and a fade filter with `alpha=1` should do it:

```
ffmpeg -y -i movie.mov -loop 1 -i overlay.png -loop 1 -i fademe.png \
-filter_complex '[0:v][1:v] overlay [V1]; \
[2:v] fade=out:25:25:alpha=1 [V2]; [V1][V2] overlay' \
faded.mp4
```

Comment: Sadly, ffmbc can't handle -filter_complex. Is there any way doing the same thing with the -vf option?

Comment: @evilheinz Unfortunately, ffmbc is quite behind in development. Is there any reason you need it and can't use FFmpeg? Ideally, ffmbc's additional features would be ported back to FFmpeg.

Comment: @evilheinz the most essential difference between this command and yours is that this one is fading out to alpha (this isn't the default); try using `[0:0]fade=out:25:25:alpha=1[fad]` in your first command.

Comment: @slhck I was planning to use ffmbc to get an ProRes4444 as output. Last time I checked the ProRes4444 encoding on ffmpeg, it didn't set the right fourcc so it was recognized as ProRes422 (HQ) in Quicktime Player. When transcoding with ffmbc the file gets correctly detected as ProRes4444.

Comment: @evilsoup the fading still looks kind of funked up when using alpha=1...